# std::stringstream across threads doesn't work as expected

Tags: c++, multithreading, iostream

I'm sending streaming data between threads using `std::iostreams` but struggling to extract the data, here's a contrived example:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <atomic>
#include <mutex>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

int main()
{
    auto stream = std::stringstream{};
    auto stop = std::atomic_bool{false};
    auto mtx = std::mutex{};

    auto thread = std::thread{[&]() {
        while(!stop) {
            auto lock = std::lock_guard{mtx};
            if (stream.peek() != decltype(stream)::traits_type::eof()) {
                auto str = std::string{};
                stream >> str;
                std::cout << str;
            }
        }
    }};

    {
        // Make sure thread is running before sending data
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);
        {
            auto lock = std::lock_guard{mtx};
            stream << "hello" << std::endl;
        }

        // Give the thread a chance to receive it
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);
    }

    stop = true;
    thread.join();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[Running it](https://godbolt.org/z/rKrqas), yields no output - debugging shows that `stream.peek()` is *always* `EOF`.  I must be doing something wrong but I can't see it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is caused by fact that you are reading data before there is anything to read (it was written).

When you have tried to read data from empty stream error flags are getting set and then any following read/write operation on such stream are not executed until error flags are cleared.

You need something what will ensure that reading will happen after writing. `std::condition_variable` can do that.

https://godbolt.org/z/fs9TGW

```cpp
int main()
{
    auto stream = std::stringstream{};
    auto mtx = std::mutex{};
    auto hasData = std::condition_variable{};
    auto readingStarted = std::condition_variable{};

    auto thread = std::thread{[&]() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{mtx};
        readingStarted.notify_one();
        hasData.wait(lock);
        auto str = std::string{};
        stream >> str;
        std::cout << str;
    }};

    {
        auto lock = std::unique_lock{mtx};
        readingStarted.wait(lock);
        stream << "hello" << std::endl;
        hasData.notify_one();
    }

    thread.join();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I'm not using sleeps in real code...  But you're right about the error flags, I didn't realise they needed manually clearing.

Comment: it is more about synchronization not clearing flags.

Comment: @cmannett85, please do not use the example in this answer as a template in production. Using a [conditional variable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) without a shared variable (condition) is an error prone way, due to [spurious wakes up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup). [This article](https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-core-guidelines-be-aware-of-the-traps-of-condition-variables) gives good explanations.